# TeamCity double quote issue in Maven Command Line parameter

Tags: continuous-integration, cucumber, teamcity, continuous-deployment

We have a CICD process in place with defined set of TCs executed always for gating process. Sometimes its not needed to run all tests, instead we would like to trigger only set of TCs based on change made by developers. Our tests are cucumber based User Stories and hence we can control the test run by Tags. My idea is to parameterize cucumber.options from teamcity's maven command line parameters field and let Dev/support people define the tag as needed.

If i mention command line parameter as

```
-Dcucumber.options="--tags %env.test.scope%"
```

my mavenized project gets the value as `cucumber.options = "--tags @Sanity` (Assume env.test.scope value is @Sanity). If you note here closely, why am i getting opening double quote? It ruins my TestRunner and none of the tests are triggered. If i remove double quote, then i get mvn error as @Sanity is not recognized as valid goal (because of space issue between --tags and @) how to define my parameter (cucumber.options) value with space in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be more related to JVM (to run Maven) and -D than TeamCity. The correct way to pass the  parameter would be
"-Dcucumber.options=--tags %env.test.scope%" as it should get as a single parameter to JVM and then be parsed to "cucumber.options" parameter with "--tags %env.test.scope%" value.

Comment: though i was able to solve this problem with @Yaegor answer, i am just curious to know how JVM parsed the value here and why last double quote missed?